# Nuxt Middleware returns default store state, even after mutating vuex in my components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use a middleware to block unauthenticated users from accessing a certain page. The problem i am having is when i try to get store.state.user, i get default values ,

```js
{
  loggedIn:false,
  loggedInUser: null,
  newUser:false
}
```

However when i access state in my component i get:

```js
{
  "loggedIn":true,
  "loggedInUser":{"myobject with sensitive dat "}},
  "newUser":false
}
```

If i inspect using vue dev tools i get the correct state.What coud i be doing wrong

Comment: How do you mutate it? We can tell you what is buggy if we don't see the actual code.

Comment: There isn't enough information to affirm, but probably when the middleware is called the store values were not mutated yet, so when you require them the store defaults to the original state values. You should ensure that the actions and mutations that modify the values of interest are finished when you query them from the middleware. That can be done asynchronously dispatching an action and then checking the values after the Promise resolves.

Comment: How/where are you using the middleware?